# storing date value as "Long" instead of "Date" in Elastic-Search index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elastic-Search index which stores products with  'createdTime' field which signifies when a document/product is added, currently i am saving 'createdTime' as 'Long' instead of 'Date' and in that field i am storing milliseconds from epoch, My question is will storing 'createdTime' as 'Long' instead of 'Date' makes sorting or any such operations slow.

ES version: 2.4.1

Comment: Dates are ultimately stored/indexed as long anyway. You can see that when sorting by date, the `sort` array contains a long number and not a date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Long is faster **but let Elastic handle that**.

Internally, fields with **Date datatype are stored as long**.
Following is the excerpt from [Elastic Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/date.html):

> Internally, dates are converted to UTC (if the time-zone is specified) and stored as a long number representing milliseconds-since-the-epoch

Storing the date as long datatype requires you to do extra processing on your side.
In addition, you are loosing the ability to view the date field as like date. For ease of use, looking at a long date isn't right.

If you use Date datatype, elastic will store the field in its inverted index as a long value. However, it will convert it to viewable date format before retrieving it back to you.

So, just use Date datatype.

Comment: One argument for storing time data as a number is if you need higher precision than just milliseconds. The millisecond precision is very limiting in some use cases. In that circumstance, I would advise to store both values, though.

Comment: @shailesh my guess is  it will be performance overhead if we allow ES to reconvert "Long" to "date", instead wont it be  easy to get date as long and convert it into Date usingserver side code.

Comment: Date is an inbuilt data type in ES. The handling of Date to store as a long value is at the core of ES and there must be optimization done for this by ES engineers. Believe in it. You may think doing this conversion in your server code is easy for you but that's too an overhead for you. For Elastic, this isn't an overhead. It is how Elastic works internally. You can better check ES documentation to know which all things you would miss if you provide date as long and not a ISO date.